# Sending mail using Gmail - exception "The SMTP server requires a secure connection"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, gmail

Aim: send mail with random number if user need to reset or forgot password

Till now what i have done is

**View**

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
Email Address:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="250" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button Text="Send" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

**Source code**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string username = string.Empty;
                string password = string.Empty;
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, [Password] FROM tbl_Detailstbl WHERE Email_Id = @Email"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                username = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                                password = sdr["Password"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                    mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
                    mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Your password is {1}.<br /><br />Thank You.", username, password);
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
                    NetworkCred.UserName = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
                    NetworkCred.Password = "asfsdfg";
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.Send(mm);
                    lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblMessage.Text = "Password has been sent to your email address.";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblMessage.Text = "This email address does not match our records.";
                }


   }
```

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in
>   System.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional information:
>   The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Please give me a fine solution for this error

Answer (score 2):

There is security setting which you should turn off in your gmail account(for the account to which you send the mail).

Check this [LINK](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: If I remember there is also something called dual authorization, which too needs to be turned off. Its called 2 step verification.

Comment: This setting should cover everything, about this exception.

Comment: Are you sure it is turn off for the receiver email

Comment: Receiver email has nothing to do with it. Its just sending protocol.

Answer (score 2):

My code works, but I don't use default credentials.

Here's the complete code:

```
var addressFrom = new MailAddress("joe.doe@gmail.com");
var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential(addressFrom.Address, "mypassword")
        };

var message = new MailMessage
        {
            Subject = _sSubject,
            Body = _sMessage,
            From = addressFrom
        };

var sTo = _sRecepients; // comma separated

message.To.Add(sTo);
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: while i change true -> false am getting The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Answer (score -1):

Goto
https://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

And Turn On "Allow less secure apps: ON"